# Text from file not reading into arrays

Tags: c++

This portion of my program is intended to read in a list of names and grades of students, then average them together and display them.

I declared a function as such:
`int loadStudentNamesGrades(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], 
 string fileName, int maxStudents);`

Here is the Definition:

```
int loadStudentNamesGrades(string students[],
                           int grades[][MAX_GRADES],
                           string fileName,
                           int maxStudents)
{
    ifstream inFile; // input file stream
    string nameFile; // name of file
    string studentName; // name of student
    int numStudents = 0; // number of students initialized to 0

    inFile.open(fileName); // open the file
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Unable to Open File!\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxStudents && (inFile >> studentName >> numStudents);
            i++, numStudents++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            inFile >> grades[i][j];
        }

        students[i] = studentName;
    }

    inFile.close();

    return numStudents;
}
```

When I try to run my program, my menu displays but none of the values from the text file populate. As far as I know my file is opening properly because it does not return an error.

Comment: Unrelated: What is the difference between `i` and `numStudents`? You can probably combine the two.

Comment: did u try stepping through with a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it reads into the arrays, but you are not returning those. Try passing your arrays by reference, something like this:

```
int loadStudentNamesGrades(string (&students)[10], int (&grades)[10][MAX_GRADES],
                           string fileName, int maxStudents)
```

You could also think about using `vector`s instead of arrays.